# Google Drive API to "publish to web" a .pptx file uploaded to google drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am successfully uploading .pptx file to google drive from my java web application. I have given share permission to the file. I want to publish it to web from my application so that I can get the embed code or link that I can use to embed my slide in my website. I have tried modifying the webViewLink and placed it inside an iframe but it fails to display the content. Can anyone please help me achieve this in java. Below is the code I am using and also the iframe link I am using in my HTML page.

```
 public String uploadFile(String fileName, java.io.File convFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {  
    
    String linkPrefix = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/";
    String linkSufix = "/embed?start=true&loop=true&delayms=5000&rm=minimal";

    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
    //fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.presentation");
    //fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
    
    
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("powerpoint/pptx", convFile);
    
    File file = driveClient.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id, webViewLink, headRevisionId, webContentLink")
        .execute();
    
    Permission permission = new Permission();
    permission.setRole("reader");
    permission.setType("anyone");
    
    String webViewLink = file.getWebViewLink();
    String webContentLink = file.getWebContentLink();
    String uniqueFileId = file.getId();
    String revisionId = file.getHeadRevisionId();
    Log.info("revisionId :"+revisionId);
    driveClient.permissions().create(uniqueFileId, permission).execute();
    
    Revision content = new Revision();
    content.setPublishAuto(true);
    content.setPublished(true);
    content.setPublishedOutsideDomain(true);    
    
    Revision link = driveClient.revisions().update(uniqueFileId, revisionId, content).execute();

    
    Log.info(link.toPrettyString());
    Log.info("File WebViewLink======>>>>>>"+file.getWebViewLink()+" : "+file.getId()+" : "+revisionId+" : "+webContentLink);
    String uniqueLink = webViewLink.replace("edit?", "embed?");
    //uniqueLink = webViewLink;
    uniqueLink = uniqueLink+linkSufix;
    
    //String uniqueLink = linkPrefix+uniqueFileId+linkSufix;
    
    String returnLink = uniqueLink;
    System.out.println("Content Link :"+returnLink);
    
    return returnLink;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1keAUxA01xnEpkxSjyGOyL4G7UuMpA245/embed?usp=drivesdk&amp;ouid=104530993132444783441&amp;rtpof=true&amp;sd=true&amp;start=true&amp;loop=true&amp;delayms=5000&amp;rm=minimal" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Wbviewlink will only work if its a google slides file "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation" and if the current user actaully has access to it.  I dont think the google drive web application will let you open it in a iframe try opening it in a new window.

Comment: Thankyou DalmTo. When i use "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation" it gives error  nullpointerexception for revision id.

Comment: But when i remove the code for revision it actually works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String uploadFile(String fileName, java.io.File convFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {  

String linkPrefix = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/";
String linkSufix = "/embed?start=true&loop=true&delayms=5000&rm=minimal";

File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.presentation");

FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("powerpoint/pptx", convFile);

File file = driveClient.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id, webViewLink, headRevisionId, webContentLink")
    .execute();

Permission permission = new Permission();
permission.setRole("reader");
permission.setType("anyone");

String webViewLink = file.getWebViewLink();
String webContentLink = file.getWebContentLink();
String uniqueFileId = file.getId();
String revisionId = file.getHeadRevisionId();
Log.info("revisionId :"+revisionId);
driveClient.permissions().create(uniqueFileId, permission).execute();

Log.info("File WebViewLink======>>>>>>"+file.getWebViewLink()+" : "+file.getId()+" : "+revisionId+" : "+webContentLink);
String uniqueLink = webViewLink.replace("edit?", "embed?");
uniqueLink = uniqueLink+linkSufix;

String returnLink = uniqueLink;
System.out.println("Content Link :"+returnLink);

return returnLink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again to DalmTo.